# Chart.js divide stepSize in equal amount of steps

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js3

Using `chart.js 3.x` how to divide the Y-Axis in an equal number of steps that should not exceed more than the total number of three steps.

Example chart,
I have set the step size which will divide the Y-Axis into three equal steps but it is ignored.
https://jsfiddle.net/0awxe539/3/

```
Step size calculation: 
stepSize = ((Math.abs(min) + max) / 2);
```

I want to have the Y-Axis divided into max three equal steps.
If `min is 0` and `max is 0.5` then the chart should have steps `0`, `0.25` and `0.5`.

Adding `maxTicksLimit:3` has some random behaviour and some times I see only 2 ticks and not three.

Also my chart data is dynamic and I am caculating and updating min, max and stepSize at the run time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't use both maxTicksLimit and stepsize together. One way to solve it is to declare the data before the config and calculate stepSize there. Then you can put max, min and stepsize values from there. I also used fixedStepSize.

```
let data =[
    {x:1, y:0.49},
  {x:2, y:0.6},
  {x:3, y:-0.18},
  {x:4, y:0.76},
  {x:5, y:0.48},
  {x:6, y:0.76},
  {x:7, y:0.1},
  {x:8, y:-0.24},
  {x:9, y:0.34},
  {x:10, y:0.42},
  {x:11, y:0.79},
  {x:12, y:-0.21}
]

let values = data.map(item => item.y)
let min = Math.min(...values)
let max = Math.max(...values)
let stepSize = ((Math.abs(min) + max) / 2); 

var config = {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: "My First dataset",
      backgroundColor: chartColors.red,
      borderColor: chartColors.red,
      showLine: true,
      data: data,
      lineTension: 0,
      fill: false,
    },]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js Line Chart'
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'label',
    },
    hover: {
      mode: 'nearest',
      intersect: true
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: {
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Test'  
        },
        ticks:
        {
            min: 1,
            max:17,
            stepSize: 5,
        },
        distribution: 'linear',
      },
      yAxes: {
        display: true,
        beginAtZero: true,
        type: 'linear',
        max: max,
        min: min,
        ticks: {
          fontColor: "#ffffff",
          stepSize: stepSize,
          fixedStepSize:stepSize,
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Value'
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: My data is dynamic and I am doing the stepSize calculation at the run time. Also min max is updated at run time, but chart is ignoring the step size as per given fiddle.